# understanding Clojure futures

Tags: clojure, future

I am trying to understand Clojure futures, and I've seen examples from the common Clojure books out there, and there are examples where futures are used for parallel computations (which seems to makes sense).

However, I am hoping someone can explain the behavior of a simple example adapted from O'Reilly's Programming Clojure book.

```
(def long-calculation (future (apply + (range 1e8))))
```

When I try to dereference this, by doing

```
(time @long-calculation)
```

It returns the correct result (4999999950000000), but almost instantly (in 0.045 msecs) on my machine.

But when I call the actual function, like so

```
(time (apply + (range 1e8)))
```

I get the correct result as well, but the time taken is much larger (~ 5000 msecs).

When I dereference the future, my understanding is that a new thread is created on which the expression is evaluated - in which case I would expect it to take around 5000 msec as well.

How come the dereferenced future returns the correct result so quickly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The calculation in a future starts as soon as you create the future (in a separate thread). In your case, the calculation starts as soon as you execute `(def long-calculation ....)`

Dereferencing will do one of two things:

- If the future has not completed, block until it completes and then return the value (this could take an arbitrary amount of time, or even never complete if the future fails to terminate)
- If the future has completed, return the result. This is almost instantaneous (which is why you are seeing very fast dereference returns)

You can see the effect by comparing the following:

```
;; dereference before future completes
(let [f (future (Thread/sleep 1000))]
  (time @f))
=> "Elapsed time: 999.46176 msecs"

;; dereference after future completes
(let [f (future (Thread/sleep 1000))]
  (Thread/sleep 2000)
  (time @f))
=> "Elapsed time: 0.039598 msecs"
```

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to using a large number of futures? I've been writing some code that does numerically intensive computations in a number of places. Instead of using native Java arrays or doing type hinting, can I just write idiomatic functional code and `future` the results of these computations instead?

Comment: Futures are fairly lightweight but do have some overhead, so I would avoid using them for extremely small computations. If you want to do computations in parallel, consider using `pmap` - which is a concurrent version of `map` that uses futures under the hood. Having said that, if your code really is numerically intensive you are probably best using both Java arrays *and* pmap/futures if you want to get t he best out of your CPU time.

Comment: I have tried to play around with pmap, but have found it useful only when the data size is "large" (how large is somewhat subjective, of course). I've been learning Clojure by implementing some simple digital signal processing functions, and there is a noticeable speed advantage with using native Java arrays over a functional style with the seq abstraction in single processor/thread mode. If I use futures, the speed-up is so immense that it really doesn't matter whether I use native or functional code. Feels like I am missing something obvious.